# catlin multitype of a particular domain

Tags: several-complex-variables

This is a remark in a paper by Jiye Yu, "multitypes of convex domains".\
For a smoothly bounded domain $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$, and suppose that it is defined by the defining function $r(z,w)=2 \Re w+2 \Re z^2+|z|^4$ in  a neighborhood of origin $0\in {\partial \Omega}$. Then Catlin  multitype $\mathcal M(\partial \Omega,0)=(1,4).$ Can someone please explain how to obtain this, mainly what steps to follow in order to obtain this?